# c - pcap filter expression

Tags: c, tcp, filter, network-programming, pcap

I was wondering how the input data in this expression actually works.

```
char *filter = "dst host 172.17.14.90 and ip";
```

From what I understand the `dest host` bit and the following IPv4 address defines what address the recieved packet should be addressed to.

The man page was a bit confusing on that point saying:

> dst host host
>   True  if  the  IPv4/v6  destination field of the packet is host,
>               which may be either an address or a name.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/pcap-filter/

so is that what it means? and as for the `and ip` bit I have no clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right about the first bit:

```
dst host 172.17.14.90
```

means that the packet should be addressed to `172.17.14.90`.

The second one:

```
ip
```

like the manpage says is an abbreviation for:

```
ether proto ip
```

which means that the packet must be sent using the IP protocol.

So, to sum up: the packet must be sent using the IP protocol to the host having IP address `172.17.14.90`.

---

As a note, the above could be expressed simpler using:

```
ip dst host 172.17.14.90
```

(the shorter syntax is explained near `host` explanation in the manpage)

Comment: Thanks! very well explained :)